A movie about a chef and a woman who share a studio in NY
So, this movie was shot in the 80s or really early 90s. It was about a woman who moves in a house a friend of her was nice enough to offer. Unfortunately he has already offered the same house (something like a 2-staired studio in NY) to a chef. The woman and the man fall in love but she suspects him on cheating on her and they broke up. He becomes the face of some frozen food product and she cries every-time she sees his face on the wrap. Finally he proposes with a ring in a champagne glass.
Can't remember the actors, nor the movie name. Any help, please? 

This could be The Night We Never Met, (1993).  Sam, played by Matthew Broderick

agrees to share the occupancy of another flat: he gets two nights a
  week, the owner (a sleazy frat-boy yuppie named Brian, soon to be
  married) and Ellen (a would-be painter seeking relief from her boring
  marriage) each get their separate nights in the flat.

Ellen, played by Annabella Sciorra, is a painter, and Sam leaves samples of his cooking in the refrigerator for her, but she mistakenly thinks they are from the sleazy owner.

No, unfortunately this is not the one I am searching for. Thanks anyway :)
